# Pytest cannot import source file. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: pytest

This is my folder structure:

```
 tree -L 2
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
├── alembic
│   ├── README
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── clients
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── binance_client.py
│   └── slack_client.py
├── helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── math_helpers.py
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── pair.py
├── requirements.txt
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── test_pair.py
```

When I run this test in the `tests` folder:

```
from models.pair import Pair


def test_name():
    coin = "some_coin"
    underlying_asset = "BTC"
    pair = Pair(coin, underlying_asset)
    print(pair)
```

I get an error.

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/stride-admin/kittycapital/tests/test_pair.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_pair.py:1: in <module>
    from models.pair import Pair
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
=========================================================================================================================== short test summary info ============================================================================================================================
ERROR tests/test_pair.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

In the root directory (same level as `clients`, `tests`, `models`) when I run pytest I get the above error. What am I doing wrong?

When I do this in my test file:

```
from ..models.pair import Pair


def test_name():
    coin = "some_coin"
    underlying_asset = "BTC"
    pair = Pair(coin, underlying_asset)
    print(pair)
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/stride-admin/kittycapital/tests/test_pair.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_pair.py:1: in <module>
    from ..models.pair import Pair
models/pair.py:1: in <module>
    from clients.binance_client import BinanceClient, BinanceAPIError
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clients'
```

So that feels wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pytest` in the root directory?

Comment: No... but why does this work? I can't just run pytest? What is going on?

Comment: Using `python -m` adds the current directory to the Python path, so your imports will work correctly.